# If n is equal to 2, then Why n *= 3 + 5 result is not equal to n = n * 3 + 5

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a variable called n, and I fill it with 2
let n = 2;

And I want to do some math on it like (n * 3 + 5)
Why these results are not the same?

1) n = n * 3 + 5; // 11

2) n *= 3 + 5; // 16

Isn't it true that (n *= whatever) is equal to (n = n * whatever)?

Comment: In the second example the right handside which is `3+5` is evaluated first and then multiplied with `n`.

Comment: with *= and /= consider the right side to have parenthesis because the two sides of an assignment expression are evaluated separately

Comment: You are right, and `whatever` is `3 + 5`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `n *= 3 + 5` is `n = n * (3 + 5)`, not `n = n * 3 + 5` (which is `n = (n * 3) + 5`).

Details. This:

```
n *= 3 + 5
```

is

```
n = n * (3 + 5)
```

which is (for `n = 2`)

```
n = 2 * 8
```

which is 16.

But this:

```
n = n * 3 + 5
```

is (for `n = 2`)

```
n = 2 * 3 + 5
```

which is

```
n = (2 * 3) + 5
```

which is

```
n = 6 + 5
```

which is `11`.